# Is there any way to enable or disable check box RTE below the bodytext for tt_news in Typo3

Tags: typo3

Generally there will be checkbox for disable rte in normal content element.
I need same functionality for ttnews rte.

Any suggestions how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

In the folder(s) where your news records are stored, paste this into the TypoScript Configuration (in the page properties):

```
RTE.default.disabled = 1
```